# Pycharm: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, pycharm, python-2.x

I am working on a Python project in Pycharm (`2020.1.2`) on Windows 10.

For this project, I cannot use the standard Python interpreter, I have to use my own located at `C:\some\path\here\python\27_64\python.exe` (Python 2.7.3).

Backstory may be important:

I have added this path to the system path for both myself and all users, and placed it ahead of `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps` to try to prevent the Microsoft store from popping up whenever I try to run `python` on the command line - however I don't feel like this change to the path variable has made a difference, as the Microsoft store still pops up.

I **can** start a Python shell by running `C:\some\path\here\python\27_64\python.exe`, so I know it technically works. When I do so; the `sys.path` is as follows:

```
['', 'C:\\another_place\\Python_2.7.3_x64\\python27.zip',
'C:\\some\\path\\here\\python\\27_64\\DLLs',
'C:\\some\\path\\here\\python\\27_64\\lib',
'C:\\some\\path\\here\\python\\27_64\\lib\\plat-win',
'C:\\some\\path\\here\\python\\27_64\\lib\\lib-tk',
'C:\\some\\path\\here\\python\\27_64',
'C:\\some\\path\\here\\python\\27_64\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Anyway, when I try to run a Python console (not even my script), this is the message I get in Pycharm:

```
C:\some\path\here\python\27_64\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --port=59771
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 5, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.pydev_rpc import make_rpc_client, start_rpc_server, start_rpc_server_and_make_client
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\pydev_rpc.py", line 1, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\some\path\here\python\27_64\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have gone to `Settings`>`Project:[name]`>`Project Interpreter` and set it to `C:\some\path\here\python\27_64\python.exe` (and rebooted Pycharm to be sure). That said; in the settings window no packages are shown and it claims that Python packaging tools can not be found.
[image: picture of Pycharm settings window, the file path is to the interpreter is C:\some\path\here\python\27_64\python.exe, a message says the Python packaging tools can't be found, the link "install packages" is circled in red]
When I click the link to install them (circled in red), they can not be installed due to this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

Are there other variables or settings I need to change?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Uninstalling the first Python on my Path (`C:\\another_place\\Python_2.7.3_x64\\python27.zip`) just makes everything so much worse

**EDIT 2**
I added the `PATH` variable manually to both the Python console settings and to the Run/Debug settings in PyCharm (and restarted the program), the result is still the same

Comment: When you run your custom Python, what is the contents of `sys.path`?  I suspect it has some references to a standard Python installation elsewhere on your system, which might contain incompatible versions of files that your Python needs (in this case specifically, `_socket.pyd` most likely).

Comment: @jasonharper I added the `sys.path` output to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. This procedure fixed my issue.
Try the following:

- run `print(os.environ['PATH'])` in the system terminal using the same interpreter
- copy the result and add as PATH environment variable to your Run/Debug Configuration
- do the same for Python Console settings

I hope it will work.

Comment: It supposedly imported the system variables but just to be sure I followed your instructions but that didn't make a difference

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the interpreter is not being recognized by the windows as a result of which you are unable to install packages.
Also, I suppose the interpreter should be present in the bin folder of your python folder. The interpreter does not have a .exe extension.

I would suggest installing anaconda python 2.7 64 Bit windows package installer and using the condo environment and work on python 2.7

Here is a link I found for Python 2.7 on Windows hope this helps:
https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html

Comment: That's right, it is just not recognized. But in Python for Windows there's **no** bin folder and interpreter **has** the `.exe` extension.

Answer (score 0):

Had the similar issue, in my case it was always trying to find libraries in PostgreSQL installation directory.

Mentioning `sys.path` helped me here! I tried printing it from inside my script and realized that PostgreSQL directories appear earlier in the list than Python directories.

SO, how I finally fixed it -- added PYTHONPATH environment variable to my Run configuration in PyCharm like this (replace with paths to your Python installation directory):
`PYTHONPATH=D:\PROGRAMS\Python\Python3.9\DLLs\;D:\PROGRAMS\Python\Python3.9\lib\;D:\PROGRAMS\Python\Python3.9\;D:\PROGRAMS\Python\Python3.9\lib\site-packages`

This helps to put desired directories at the beginning of the list, thus they are searched first and required libraries are found as it is supposed to work.